# Conditional override in derived class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, sfinae

I have a `Container` class that holds objects whose type may be derived from any combination of some base classes (`TypeA`, `TypeB`, etc.). The base class of `Container` has virtual methods that return a pointer to the contained object; these should return `nullptr` if the contained object isn't derived from the expected class. I would like to selectively override the base's methods based on `Container`'s template parameter. I tried using SFINAE as follows, but it doesn't compile. I would like to avoid specializing `Container` for every possible combination because there could be many.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TypeA {};
class TypeB {};
class TypeAB: public TypeA, public TypeB {};

struct Container_base {
    virtual TypeA* get_TypeA() {return nullptr;}
    virtual TypeB* get_TypeB() {return nullptr;}
};

template <typename T>
struct Container: public Container_base
{
    Container(): ptr(new T()) {}

    //Override only if T is derived from TypeA
    auto get_TypeA() -> enable_if<is_base_of<TypeA, T>::value, TypeA*>::type
    {return ptr;}

    //Override only if T is dervied from TypeB
    auto get_TypeB() -> enable_if<is_base_of<TypeB, T>::value, TypeB*>::type
    {return ptr;}

private:
    T* ptr;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Container<TypeA> typea;
    Container<TypeB> typeb;
    Container<TypeAB> typeab;

    cout << typea.get_TypeA() << endl; //valid pointer
    cout << typea.get_TypeB() << endl; //nullptr

    cout << typeb.get_TypeA() << endl; //nullptr
    cout << typeb.get_TypeB() << endl; //valid pointer

    cout << typeab.get_TypeA() << endl; //valid pointer
    cout << typeab.get_TypeB() << endl; //valid pointer

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, the reason why your approach does not work is that the derived class getters hide the base class getters during the name lookup phase – even though they are later eliminated by the SFINAE that happens as part of template type deduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... or you could change your approach to a simpler one:

```
template <typename T>
struct Container: public Container_base
{
    TypeA* get_TypeA() override
    {
        if constexpr(is_base_of_v<TypeA, T>)
            return ptr;
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    ...
};
```

and rely on optimizer to smooth away any wrinkles. Like replacing multiple `return nullptr` functions with one (in final binary). Or removing dead branch of code if your compiler doesn't support `if constexpr`.

**Edit:**

... or (if you insist on using SFINAE) something along these lines:

```
template<class B, class T, enable_if_t< is_base_of_v<B, T>>...> B* cast_impl(T* p) { return p; }
template<class B, class T, enable_if_t<!is_base_of_v<B, T>>...> B* cast_impl(T* p) { return nullptr; }

template <typename T>
struct Container: public Container_base
{
    ...

    TypeA* get_TypeA() override { return cast_impl<TypeA>(ptr); }
    TypeB* get_TypeB() override { return cast_impl<TypeB>(ptr); }

private:
    T* ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

CRTP to the rescue!

```
template<class T, class D, class Base, class=void>
struct Container_getA:Base {};
template<class T, class D, class Base, class=void>
struct Container_getB:Base {};

template<class T, class D, class Base>
struct Container_getA<T, D, Base, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>{}>>:
  Base
{
  TypeA* get_TypeA() final { return self()->ptr; }
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
};

template<class T, class D, class Base>
struct Container_getB<T, D, Base, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<TypeB,T>{}>>:
  Base
{
  TypeB* get_TypeB() final { return self()->ptr; }
  D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
};

template <class T>
struct Container: 
  Container_getA< T, Container<T>,
    Container_getB< T, Container<T>,
      Container_base
    >
  >
{
    Container(): ptr(new T()) {}

public: // either public, or complex friend declarations; just make it public
    T* ptr;
};
```

and done.

You can do a bit of work to permit:

```
struct Container: Bases< T, Container<T>, Container_getA, Container_getB, Container_getC >
```

or the like where we fold the CRTP bases in.

You can also clean up your syntax:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct types {};

template<class T>
struct tag_t {using type=T;};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

Then, instead of having a pile of named getters, have:

```
template<class List>
struct Container_getters;

template<class T>
struct Container_get {
  virtual T* get( tag_t<T> ) { return nullptr; }
};
template<class...Ts>
struct Container_getters<types<Ts...>>:
  Container_get<Ts>...
{
   using Container_get<Ts>::get...; // C++17
   template<class T>
   T* get() { return get(tag<T>); }
};
```

and now a central type list can be used to maintain the set of types you can get from the container.

We can then use that central type list to write the CRTP intermediate helpers.

```
template<class Actual, class Derived, class Target, class Base, class=void>
struct Container_impl_get:Base {};
template<class Actual, class Derived, class Target, class Base>
struct Container_impl_get<Actual, Derived, Target, Base,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Target, Actual>{}>
>:Base {
  using Base::get;
  virtual Target* get( tag_t<Target> ) final { return self()->ptr; }
  Derived* self() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};
```

and now we just need to write the fold machinery.

```
template<class Actual, class Derived, class List>
struct Container_get_folder;
template<class Actual, class Derived, class List>
using Container_get_folder_t=typename Container_get_folder<Actual, Derived, List>::type;

template<class Actual, class Derived>
struct Container_get_folder<Actual, Derived, types<>> {
  using type=Container_base;
};
template<class Actual, class Derived, class T0, class...Ts>
struct Container_get_folder<Actual, Derived, types<T0, Ts...>> {
  using type=Container_impl_get<Actual, Derived, T0,
    Container_get_folder_t<Actual, Derived, types<Ts...>>
  >;
};
```

so we get

```
using Container_types = types<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>;
struct Container_base:Container_getters<Container_types> {
};

template <typename T>
struct Container: Container_get_folder_t<T, Container<T>, Container_types>
{
    Container(): ptr(new T()) {}
    T* ptr;
};
```

and now we can extend this by simply adding a type to `Container_types`.

Callers who want a specific type can either do:

```
Container_base* ptr = /* whatever */;
ptr->get<TypeA>()
```

or

```
ptr->get(tag<TypeA>);
```

both work equally well.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71eefeb339c6f0dc) -- it does use a C++14 feature or two (namely variable templates in `tag`), but you can replace `tag<X>` with `tag_t<X>{}`.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot to unpack here. I tested the first solution and it works (thanks!), however I don't recognize some of the syntax: what are the empty braces after `std::is_base_of_t` doing? As in `std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>{}>`

Comment: @Carlton - `std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>{}` create an object of type `std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>`. An object of type `std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>` is convertible to boolean (returning `std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>::value`). So `std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>{}`, in a context requiring a boolean, is (substantially) a shorter way to write `std::is_base_of<TypeA,T>::value`.

Comment: @Carlton I'd also consider `std::is_convertible_t< Actual*, Target* >{}`, which permits a `get<void>()` or handles `const` storage or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using SFINAE as follows, but it doesn't compile. I would like to avoid specializing Container for every possible combination because there could be many.

Unfortunately virtual functions and template functions are incompatible. And you can't use SFINAE with not template methods, so

```
auto get_TypeA()
   -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<TypeA, T>::value, TypeA*>::type
 {return ptr;}
```

doesn't works because the `T` type is a template argument of the class, not a template argument of the method.

To enable SFINAE, you can templatize the method as follows

```
template <typename U = T>
auto get_TypeA()
   -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<TypeA, U>::value, TypeA*>::type
 {return ptr;}
```

and now SFINAE works, but `get_TypeA()` is a template method now so can't be virtual anymore.

If you really needs virtual functions, you can solve with inheritance and template specialization (see Yakk's answer).

But, if you don't really need that `get_TypeX()` functions are virtual, I propose you a completely different (and simpler, I suppose) solution, completely based over a couple (regardless the number of `TypeX` classes) of template methods.

I mean... if you write a couple of alternative `get_Type()` template methods as follows

```
  template <typename U>
  auto get_Type()
     -> std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_base_of<U, T>::value, U*>
   { return ptr; }

  template <typename U>
  auto get_Type()
     -> std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_base_of<U, T>::value, U*>
   { return nullptr; }
```

you don't need `Container_base` any more and the type of the requested pointer become the template parameter of the method that is called as follows

```
typea.get_Type<TypeA>()
```

The following is a full working C++14 example (if you need a C++11 solution, just use `typename std::enable_if<>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<>`)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class TypeA {};
class TypeB {};
class TypeAB: public TypeA, public TypeB {};

template <typename T>
struct Container
 {
   private:
      T* ptr;

   public:
      Container(): ptr{new T{}} {}

      template <typename U>
      auto get_Type()
         -> std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_base_of<U, T>::value, U*>
       { return ptr; }

      template <typename U>
      auto get_Type()
         -> std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_base_of<U, T>::value, U*>
       { return nullptr; }
};

int main ()
 {
   Container<TypeA> typea;
   Container<TypeB> typeb;
   Container<TypeAB> typeab;

   std::cout << typea.get_Type<TypeA>() << std::endl; //valid pointer
   std::cout << typea.get_Type<TypeB>() << std::endl; //nullptr

   std::cout << typeb.get_Type<TypeA>() << std::endl; //nullptr
   std::cout << typeb.get_Type<TypeB>() << std::endl; //valid pointer

   std::cout << typeab.get_Type<TypeA>() << std::endl; //valid pointer
   std::cout << typeab.get_Type<TypeB>() << std::endl; //valid pointer
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I can just override my base class's virtual functions in terms of your `get_Type` template member functions; i.e. `TypeA* get_TypeA() override {return get_Type<TypeA>();}`. It produces the correct behavior.

Comment: @Carlton - yes... if you really need to work with a virtual function for every `TypeX` type...